# While loop returns nothing

Tags: python, python-2.7

The function should print one list - the top list when 'paige' is inclusive in the list. However, it returns nothing. Where does it go wrong?

Also, is `str(list)` the best way here to store output in the result?

```
def addingpaige(s):
   list = ["paige", "peter", "eric"]
   result = ""
   while "paige" and "peter" in list:
        result = result + str(list)
   return result
print addingpaige(["paige", "peter", "eric"])
```

Comment: `while "paige" in lst and "peter" in lst`. Test each containment separately

Comment: How will this terminate? What do you expect as output?

Comment: and since the `list` is not modified anywhere inside the body of loop, it will be an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

1. It seems like you are giving the list `["paige", "peter", "eric"]` as an argument to `addingpaige()`, but then not doing anything with it, instead defining `list` in that function.
2. `while "paige" and "peter" in list:`: `and` doesn't work this way. Instead, test `"paige" in list` and then `"peter" in list`. In other words, this becomes `while "paige" in list and "peter" in list:`
3. The while condition is always `True` in this case, so this gives you an infinite loop. Only have a while condition that can change between iterations, and/or have something in your while loop that can break out of it.
4. `list` is a keyword so maybe choose a different name for your list.

It's not clear to me what you want to do, though. As it stands, the code is nonsensical as it contains an infinite loop. What should `addingpaige()` print, based on what condition?

Answer (score 0):

`"paige" and "peter"` actually evaluates to `"peter"`. This code is effectively saying: `while` the string `"peter"` is present `in list` keep looping.